# My Character is Destroyed when I Move any Bone

Tags: animation, mesh, rigging, bones, parent

[image: My Problem Like it]

When I've finished my character mesh and I parent it to my bones, it makes it stretch when I move any bone.

All the mesh have effect and moving Random.

this link for my blender file:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/11BLVjRA3f0ixPRzBzymJMkamyy8-tEDw/view?usp=sharing

[image: This is when I moving the Hand Controller]

Comment: try subdividing the mesh I think that should help

Comment: I did it maram but nothing happen thanks for try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you see your face normals are flipped, you need to recalculate (select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

Also your feet are tweaking because of their *Pole Target*, I'm not sure what you are trying to do there but try a rotation of the feet bone in *Edit* mode: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>-90</kbd> for the left foot and +90° for the right bone.

Comment: Thanks for that help, you take images and explain very well, ☺️ man wtf this success and very useful bro i cant say anything but you helped me omfg thanks for you sir!!!!

Comment: thanks for you sir i will ask God for let you get in the right way and success in your life!! you dont know how much i waste for try to fix it ;)

Comment: how do i can support you sir ?? i will do anything for say thanks

Comment: @Rami Alyazje you're welcome   ;)